# Flutter/Dart - Button to Redirect Screen when Exception Thrown?

Tags: flutter, exception, dart, http-post

Currently when an exception is thrown the user is faced with a blank white page which simply states,

"We were not able to successfully download the json data"

But I'd like to provide a safety net by offering a button which redirects to the home page. Any ideas for how this can be done? Here's the code where the exception is thrown;

```
Future<List<ReplyContent>> downloadJSON({String replyid}) async {

  final jsonContent = "http://example.com/getpost.php";

  final response = await get(jsonContent);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List replycrafts = json.decode(response.body);
    return replycrafts
        .map((replycraft) => new ReplyContent.fromJson(replycraft))
        .toList();
  } else
    throw Exception('We were not able to successfully download the json data.');
}
```

Comment: You can update a boolean variable that shows and hides the button

Answer (score 0):

When calling the Future, you can use the `catchError` method.

```
downloadJSON().catchError((e)=> print(e)); // Example
```

Then in your widget you could have a boolean for showing the button or not.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool shouldShowButton = false;
  
  Future downloadJSON()async{
    throw("ERROR!");
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                   FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Call Future"),
                  onPressed: (){
                    downloadJSON().catchError((e)=>setState(()=> shouldShowButton = true));
                  },
                  ),
                  shouldShowButton? FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Go back"),
                  onPressed: ()=> Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  ): Container(),
                ],
              ),
        )
          ),

    );
  }
}
```

That way, when your Future is called, you can simply use `setState` to update the value of shouldShowButton to true.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate? I don't understand the connection between callFuture() and downloadJSON().catchError((e)=> print(e));

Comment: Whoops! They have no connection. The first snippet was just an example.